# Confusion with functions with static linkage

Tags: c++, linker

I'm unsure of the following code:

**.lib project**

*Unit.h*

```
namespace mynamespace {

    static void myFunction()
    {
      printf("hello world");
    }

    void myFunction2();
 }
```

*Unit.cpp*

```
#include "Unit.h"

void myFunction2() { printf("hello world"); }
```

**.exe project**

*mainapp.cpp*

```
   #include "Unit.h"

   int main()
   {
      mynamespace::myFunction();
      mynamespace::myFunction2();
      return 0;

   }
```

1) Why am I getting "unresolved external symbol" for myFunction2() ? I'm including the header and the symbol is in another translation unit, what's wrong?

2) static should mean "with internal linkage", does this mean that both mainapp.cpp and unit.cpp will have their "copy" of myFunction ?

Comment: The answer to #2 is "yes", assuming that you included `Unit.h` inside `Unit.cpp`.

Comment: Right, sorry for not having written that before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to implement the function in the namespace:

```
void mynamespace::myFunction2() { printf("hello world"); }
```

Currently, in Unit.cpp, you're defining a different function; a function with name `myFunction2` in the *global namespace*.

Answer (score 1):

... implement the function in the namespace ...

Unit.cpp

```
namespace mynamespace {
  void myFunction2() { printf("hello world"); }
}
```

Comment: The second one won't help - it's still declaring a new function in the global namespace. `void mynamespace::myFunction2() {...}` will define the correct function, and is better than the first option since it *can't* declare a new function.

Comment: What works with classes? Class member function definitions also need to be qualified with the class name if they're defined outside the class.